# How does an traceless symmetric tensor of rank two $S_{ij}$ transform under $SO(3)$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations

The irreducible tensor representations of $SO(3)$ all have odd dimensionalities given by $2j+1$ with $j=0,1,2,3,...$ etc. The representations can be designated by their dimensionalities as ${\bf 1}, {\bf 3}, {\bf 5},...$ etc, and they transform as $${\rm scalar:}~~\phi\to\phi^\prime=\phi,\\ {\rm vector:}~~V_i\to V_{i}^{\prime}=R_{ij}V_j\Rightarrow {\vec V}^\prime=\mathbb{R}{\vec V},\\{\rm traceless~symmetric~ rank-2~tensor:}~~S_{ij}\to S_{ij}^\prime=R_{ik}R_{jl}S_{kl}\Rightarrow S^\prime=\mathbb{R}S\mathbb{R}^T$$ respectively. However, instead of this, can we write the third transformation as $$S^\prime=\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})S$$ where $\mathbb{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is the $5$-dimensional representation of the $SO(3)$ generators? Is there a systematic way of showing this? Sorry for my notations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this was answered recently. The skew symmetric  $A_{ij}$ transforms in the vector "$3$" repesentation in the same way as $V_i =\epsilon_{ijk}A_{jk}$. This is because $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is an invariant tensor under SO($3$). All such invariant tensors can be regarded as Clebsh-Gordan coefficients. For examble the vector product
$$
W_i=\epsilon_{ijk} U_jV_k
$$
is an example of the $3\otimes 3= 1+3+5$. The "$1$" is the scalar product $\delta_{ij}U_iV_k$ that comes from  the invariant tensor $\delta_{ij}$, and the "$5$" is the symmetric traceless tensor  $$
W_{ij}=(U_iV_j+U_jV_i)/2- \delta_{ij} U_kV_k/3, 
$$ which  is what is left of the  $9$ dimensional reducible representation $T_{ij}= U_iV_j$ after the  other two irreducible reps have been extracted.

Comment: Is this true for higher dimensional irreducible tensor representations such as ${\bf 7}$?

Comment: Life gets more complicated for higher irreps. On needs to use Young projectors extract  the ${\rm GL}(3)$  irreps from higher order tensors, and then these reps become reducible under the restrictions ${\rm GL}(3)\to {\rm SL}(3)\to {\rm SO}(3)$. A good source is Hamermesh group theory book. I think this book is now available from Dover, and so not expensive.

Comment: SO(3) has 7-plet, 9-plet, 11-plet etc as irreps which are basically tensor representations. So they should transform by more and more factors of $R_{ij}$ (in my notation). But I am asking, instead of doing that can we use 7-dimensional, 9-dimensional , 11-dimensional representations of SO(3)?

Comment: Yes, of course. The problem is expressing the 7-by-7, 9-by-9, etc.  matrices of the $|J,m\rangle$ bases in  terms of the symmetry and trace reduced $R_{ij}$ tensor products acting on the cartesian tensor bases. This is not as easy as the $(x,y,x)\to (x+iy,z, x-iy)$ change of basis for the $j=1$ case.

Comment: Thanks. So at least for SO(3), n-plet representations are not different from irreducible tensor representations. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. The $n$-plet irreps of ${\rm SO}(N)$ are the result of decomposing the general rank-$k$ ${\rm GL}(N)$ tensor reps into  their irreducible  components.